# Find the base of the power and power with given base in python

Tags: python, math

I have a number N let's say 5451 and I want to find the base for power 50. How do I do it with python?

The answer is 1.1877622648368 according [this website (General Root calculator)](https://www.calculator.net/root-calculator.html?cvar3=50&cvar4=5451&ctype=3&x=59&y=19#general) But i need to find it with computation.

Second question. If I have the number N 5451, and I know the base 1.1877622648368, how do I find the power?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be really a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the [*n*-th root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) is the same as raising to the power 1/*n*. This is very simple to do in Python using the `**` operator (exponentiation):

```
>>> 5451**(1/50)
1.1877622648368031
```

The second one requires a [logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), which is the inverse of exponentiation. You want to take the base-1.1877622648368031 logarithm of 5451, which is done with the `log` function in the `math` module:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.log(5451, 1.1877622648368031)
50.00000000000001
```

As you can see, there's some roundoff error. This is [unavoidable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) when working with limited-precision floating point numbers. Apply the `round()` function to the result if you know that it must be an integer.

Comment: ah, i am stupid i am not thinking at all. thanks. yes i know logarithm but my brain is like dead not thinking at all crazy. ok thanks